# MongoDB Crashes after too many requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, database-performance

I'm working nodejs webservice that uses socket io and mongo db.

I am currently in the testing phase and I am testing the sending of thousands of messages with thousands of socket io connections which causes mongo to crash. the error is crashes with is as follows:

```
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEE+0x39) [0x10cbde939]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x100) [0x10cb92c80]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15invariantFailedEPKcS1_j+0x183) [0x10cb7ff53]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur13JournalWriter20_journalWriterThreadEv+0x8FC) [0x10c9ba2ac]
 mongod(_ZN5boost12_GLOBAL__N_112thread_proxyEPv+0xB1) [0x10cc121b1]
 libsystem_pthread.dylib(_pthread_body+0x8A) [0x7fff88c40899]
 libsystem_pthread.dylib(_pthread_struct_init+0x0) [0x7fff88c4072a]
 libsystem_pthread.dylib(thread_start+0xD) [0x7fff88c44fc9]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-09-29T16:29:54.206+0100 I -        [journal writer] 

***aborting after invariant() failure
```

I only have 3 connections to the database at any given time. So I don't think it's a connection overload issue.

I've noticed mongo crashes when it is under a lot of request load. Why does it crash? Should it not just add things to some processing queue?

How could I prevent this crashing. What techniques are there to managing this?

I think this may be due to hardware limitations. I was going to run this webservice on a raspberry pi. Guess I'll have to think twice before I do that.

Comment: Are you using something like mongoose? Or the native driver directly?

Comment: Yes. I am using mongoose. Do you think this could be the issue?

Comment: Could be. Where is the code where you are establishing connections? How often is the code called? Code that incorrectly implements connections can easily crash the system.

Comment: It establishes the connection once when the server loads. And once when the unit tests load. Only 2 connections required. I also have a third connection occasionally which is the ./mongo program in the mongodb bin directory so I can query the database directly if I need to. Once connection is established for the server, it isn't dropped for the duration of the server uptime. The unit test connection is dropped after all tests are run.